# Load related model in rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in ruby rails and face some difficult to achieve something.
Now I have a product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :category
```

And category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :products
```

When I call the product like so: `@products.inspect` i wan to see the category belongs to the product. My output now looks like so:

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 1, name: "Adidas", description: "Adidas is a Dutch multinational corporation that i...", price: 100, created_at: "2022-08-23 10:02:11.110159000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-08-23 10:02:11.114384000 +0000", category_id: 1>, #<Product id: 2, name: "asd", description: "12easd", price: 12, created_at: "2022-08-24 09:35:38.839809000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-08-24 09:35:38.847999000 +0000", category_id: 1>]>
```

Getting the `product.category` working fine, but, I need also the name of the category attached to this output. I need this because the product is sent to a JavaScript function and I need to call the category name from there.
What I already try is the follow:

```
def index
@products = Product.includes(:category).all
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

```
@product.to_json(include: :category)
```

And now I get the related category model